# Error package vscode extension with vsce: invalid relative path

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

- npm: 8.1.0
- vsce: 2.5.3

I have a npm package (colibri) in a local folder and a VSCode extension (vscode-teroshdl) in other folder. colibri is a dependency of vscode-teroshdl:

```
    "dependencies": {
        "colibri": "file:../colibri"
    },
```

When I try to package the VSCode extension:

```
cd colibri
npm install
cd ../vscode-terosHDL
npm install
vsce package
```

It fails with the error:

```
 ERROR  invalid relative path: extension/../colibri/node_modules/cli-progress/CHANGES.md
```

Answer (score 1):

It's almost certainly this bug: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-vsce/issues/381 as I just encountered it while trying to package [`ansible-vscode`, which uses symlinks](https://github.com/ansible/vscode-ansible/blob/v0.8.1/package.json#L465)

As mentioned in that issue, I found that running `vsce package --yarn` (even without yarn-specific files in the working copy) caused it to package as expected.

This was with node v17.6.0 darwin/amd64 and vsce 1.96.1. While testing this, I noticed my vsce was old, but I had the same experience on 2.6.7, which is the latest